# Limiting number of characters displayed for a SQL based report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to modify a report that shows health assessments using SQL. On the report, I would like to add a section for comments that were added to the health assessments. I was able to add the comment section, but I would now like to limit the number of characters displayed on the report to 1000 as opposed to 8000. I tried using SET TEXTSIZE and as then LEFT as shown below.
I'm not receiving errors using LEFT and am able to generate the report, but the command is not limiting the number of characters displayed. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

```
-- Prepare Table #ChronicCondition
  CREATE TABLE #ChronicCondition
  (
    IdApplicant INT,
    ExamDate DATETIME,
    Condition VARCHAR(500),
    TreatmentNeeded INT,
    TreatmentReceived INT,
    Status INT,
    ReasonTreatmentNotReceived INT,
    Comment VARCHAR(8000)
  )

  -- Anemia
  INSERT INTO #ChronicCondition(IdApplicant, ExamDate, Condition, TreatmentNeeded, TreatmentReceived, Status, Comment)
    SELECT  #Enroll.IdApplicant,
            HltAnemia.ExamDate,
            'Anemia',
            HltAnemia.TrtNeed,
            HltAnemia.TrtStatus,
            HltAnemia.Status,
        LEFT (HltAnemia.Comment, 100)
    FROM    #Enroll 
            JOIN HltAnemia ON HltAnemia.IdApplicant = #Enroll.IdApplicant
    WHERE   HltAnemia.Chronic = 1
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want `Comment VARCHAR(8000)` to be `varchar(100)` based off your `LEFT` function. You stated the report isn't limiting it... where is the report getting the data? A final select i suspect?

Comment: use this instead:  SUBSTRING(HltAnemia.Comment, 1, 100)

Comment: Thank you! SUBSTRING(HltAnemia.Comment, 1, 100) corrected the issue.